# EF4 LINQ - Adding Filtering on a Join

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

How do I add a FILTER CLAUSE to a JOIN TABLE ....in LINQ ?

> > AND t2.Public = 1 AND t2.Color = 'Blue'

---

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                      FROM tbl2 t2 
                     WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID 
                       AND t2.Public = 1 AND t2.Color = 'Blue') AS MyCount 
 FROM tbl1 t1
WHERE t1.State = 'CA'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like this.

```
from t1 in context.tbl1
where t1.State = "CA"
select new 
{
    t1.ID, 
    t1.Name,
    MyCount = t1.tbl2s.Count(t2 => t2.Public && t2.Color == "Blue")
}
```

That's about all the help I can give without knowing more about the names of the entities in your context, their relationships to each other, and the types of their scalar values.

Answer (score 1):

If your entities don't have navigation property between them use:

```
var data = from t1 in context.Tbl1
           join t2 in context.Tbl2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id
           where t1.State = "CA" && t2.Public == 1 && t2.Color = "Blue"
           group t1 by new { t1.Id, t1.Name } into g
           select new 
               {
                   Id = g.Key.Id,
                   Name = g.Key.Name,
                   Count = g.Count()
               };
```

If they have navigation properties use solution provided by @StriplingWarrior